# CSS: Center a background image in responsive views

Tags: html, css

Total noob here
Im doing a coming soon page with a single image background based on this template:
https://colorlib.com/etc/cs/03-comming-soon.html

What i;m trying to achieve is that when the page is opened on pc/tablet/phone, the center of the image is the fixed point (rather than top right as currently).

ive tried updating to this

```
    .main-area{ 
     position: relative; 
     height: 100vh;
     z-index: 1;
     padding: 0 20px;
     background-size: cover;
     background-origin: center;
     background-position: center center; 
     color: #fff; 
   }
```

but no luck

CSS below

```
/*
====================================================

*   [Master Stylesheet]

    Theme Name :  
    Version    :  
    Author     :  
    Author URI :  

====================================================

    TOC

    1. PRIMARY STYLES
    2. COMMONS FOR PAGE DESIGN
        JQUERY LIGHT BOX
    3. MAIN SECTION

====================================================

/* ---------------------------------
1. PRIMARY STYLES
--------------------------------- */

html{ font-size: 100%; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; margin: 0px;  padding: 0px; touch-action: manipulation; }


body{ font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; word-wrap: break-word; overflow-x: hidden; 
    color: #333; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a, ul, span, li, img, inpot, button{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{ line-height: 1.5; font-weight: inherit; }

h1,h2,h3{ font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; }

p{ line-height: 1.6; font-size: 1.05em; font-weight: 400; color: #555; }

h1{ font-size: 3.5em; line-height: 1; }
h2{ font-size: 3em; line-height: 1.1; }
h3{ font-size: 2.5em; }
h4{ font-size: 1.5em; }
h5{ font-size: 1.2em; }
h6{ font-size: .9em; letter-spacing: 1px; }

a, button{ display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; color: inherit; transition: all .3s; line-height: 1; }

a:focus, a:active, a:hover,
button:focus, button:active, button:hover,
a b.light-color:hover{ text-decoration: none; color: #E45F74; }

b{ font-weight: 500; }

img{ width: 100%; }

li{ list-style: none; display: inline-block; }

span{ display: inline-block; }

button{ outline: 0; border: 0; background: none; cursor: pointer; }

b.light-color{ color: #444; }

.icon{ font-size: 1.1em; display: inline-block; line-height: inherit; }

[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before{ line-height: inherit; }

*, *::before, *::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;} 


/* ---------------------------------
2. COMMONS FOR PAGE DESIGN
--------------------------------- */

.center-text{ text-align: center; } 

.display-table{ display: table; height: 100%; width: 100%; }

.display-table-cell{ display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }



::-webkit-input-placeholder { font-size: .9em; letter-spacing: 1px; }

::-moz-placeholder { font-size: .9em; letter-spacing: 1px; }

:-ms-input-placeholder { font-size: .9em; letter-spacing: 1px; }

:-moz-placeholder { font-size: .9em; letter-spacing: 1px; }


.full-height{ height: 100%; }

.position-static{ position: static; }

.font-white{ color: #fff; }


/* ---------------------------------
3. MAIN SECTION
--------------------------------- */

.main-area{ position: relative; height: 100vh; z-index: 1; padding: 0 20px; background-size: cover; background-origin: center; background-position: center center; color: #fff; }

.main-area:after{ content:''; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;left: 0; right: 0; z-index: -1;  
    opacity: .4; background: #000; }

.main-area .desc{ margin: 20px auto; max-width: 500px; }

.main-area .notify-btn{ padding: 13px 35px; border-radius: 50px; border: 2px solid #004A71;
    color: #fff; background: #004A71; }

.main-area .notify-btn:hover{ background: none; }

.main-area .social-btn{ position: absolute; bottom: 40px; width: 100%; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); }

.main-area .social-btn > li > a{ margin: 0 10px; padding-bottom: 7px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; }

.main-area .social-btn > li > a:after{ content:''; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; 
    transition: all .2s; height: 2px; background: #F84982; }


.main-area .social-btn > li > a:hover:after{ transform: translateX(100%); }
```

Comment: instead of cover, does background-size: contain work?

Answer (score 1):

**try this:**

```
.main-area { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[more info](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

Do not set any width, height or margins.

Try this.

```
background-image:url('url_to_image');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `background-position: center;` to your .main-area class is workin well with your demo-page.

```
.main-area {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #fff;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Maybe it could get overwritten, so you can add a '!important' after 'center':

```
background-position: center !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Height = auto is the key here which will set the image background to center and expand no matter what screen size it is on.

Let me know if it works.

```
.main-area {
  background-image:url('url_to_image');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  background-position:center
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
```